# What are session_id, session_regenerate_id and session_name used for?

Tags: php, session

ok im a newbie on sessions lets imagine that we have a little login site,

heres a logic

1. login
2. if password right = use $_SESSION[isaloginuser] = 1
3. check session to see menus with if $_SESSION[isaloginuser] = 1
4. show the menus
5. the user want to logoff
6. unset session
7. destroy session system

what it use

```
session_register
session_destroy
session_unset
session_start
```

where does the `session_id` & the `session_regenerate` or `session_name` goes in ? 
at php site it says

> session_id() is used to get or set the
>   session id for the current session.

i still just dont get it, why do we need them anyway ? in **real environment** what does it do ?

Comment: not only password but make sure that user name is also right :)

Comment: always use `session_regenerate_id` when the privilege level changes

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262620/what-additional-value-does-session-destroy-bring-when-i-am-using-session-regener) has two awesome answers on sessions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, you don’t need to use them. In general all you need is

- [`session_start`](http://php.net/session_start) to start the session handling, and
- [`session_destroy`](http://php.net/session_destroy) to destroy the stored session data (this does not modify `$_SESSION`), and
- [`session_unset`](http://php.net/session_unset) to reset the `$_SESSION` variable (but you can also do `$_SESSION = array()`).

[`session_id`](http://php.net/session_id) and [`session_name`](http://php.net/session_name) are to get and set the current session ID and session ID name (default is `PHPSESSID`). [`session_regenerate_id`](http://php.net/session_regenerate_id) can be used to regenerate/change the session ID of the current session. This might be useful if, for example, you want to refresh the session ID every 10 minutes or after changing the state of authenticity of a user associated with a session.

Comment: ok, but what does it do in the real world ? are you useing it on one of your project? for what ?

Comment: @Adam Ramadhan: What does what do in the real world?

Comment: session_id, name and regenerate.

Answer (score 10):

`session_regenerate_id()` is used in order to prevent session fixation.

Session fixation means the following: You visit a website and examine your session ID. Then you manipulate another user into visiting the site using your session ID, and signing in. Now you're signed in as that user and have his privileges, because you're both using the same session.

To prevent this, give the user a new session ID using `session_regenerate_id()` when he successfully signs in. Now only he has the session ID, and your old session ID is no longer valid.

Comment: should we add it at login ? or in logout?

Comment: It's important to do it at login. I don't think it is necessary to do it at logout, although it's not an expensive operation.

Comment: @Hammerite Good example, but everytime a user refreshes the page, the `session_regenerate_id()` is generating new sets of sessions, so doesn't this affect the session in anyway ?

Comment: session_regenerate_id() will leave a trail of active session files on server. session_regenerate_id(true) will replace old session file will new one.

Answer (score 3):

[session_register()](http://www.php.net/session_register) is depreciated in 5.3, I would suggest against using. Instead just use

```
$_SESSION['varname'] = "value";
```

session_id it just used if you want to get the session id for storing in a database, this is not "necessary" for use. session_name, just sets a name, this is not necessary. The regenerate is if you want to do a new id, this is also not necessary unless your application needs it, for a login session, I highly doubt you will use it.

The others, I hope you understand what they do (ie the unset / destroy). But hope that gives some insight.

Answer (score 2):

Session IDs are the identifier for the session. The way a server stores data about a client is in a cookie. This cookie is sent with each HTTP request to the server by that client. PHP sets a cookie to be a random string token. This token identifies the client and relates it to a set of key-value pairs. The idea of a session variable is that cookies can be easily tampered with. Session IDs, however, being random strings, are hard to duplicate and thus add security.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use session_id() when creating shopping baskets so I can track what that user has added then once I have got a response back from the payment gateway that the payment was successful, I then session_regenerate() so that when they are back on to my website their previous baskets are not visible and to me its like a new user has "entered" the shop.

Comment: `$_SESSION['cart'] = null` wouldn't do?