# What additional value does session_destroy bring when I am using session_regenerate_id(true) in PHP?

Tags: php, session

I've been reading the manual and various pages on the web including lot's of questions here on SO. However, I've still not been able to get my head around the concept of `session_destroy()` in PHP in conjunction with other means of unsetting session data.

Consider this for a site that *never registers session variables* outside the `$_SESSION` superglobal array.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
session_regenerate_id(true); // New cookie + old session file on server deleted
session_destroy();  // What does PHP do here that was not done above?
```

Please note that I have built working login-logout scripts for years. This question is not about getting things to work, but I want to **understand exactly** what is happening.

(A lot of answers here on SO also use `session_unset()` which unsets registered variables. However, I never use `session_register()`, so that seems really redundant.)

Comment: well, you've just deleted your *new* session server file, as well as the old one. I assume it will simply be re-created when you set a session value, or at the end of the script, or when whatever optimisation PHP does says it's time to save data.

Comment: (odds are that PHP never actually created that file in the first place; I hope it would wait until there is actual data to put in it)

Comment: As is explained in the accepted answer, session_regenerate_id(true) calls the same underlying function as session_destroy, making that extra line redundant in my case.

Comment: I don't think you get it still, `session_regenerate_id(true)` is equivalent to `session_destroy()` followed by `session_start()` except that you retain the previous session data.

Comment: If you look at the code in the example I have set `$_SESSION` to an empty array. Thus, there is no session data to retain. But since there is a session still in place I can of course populate the array with new data without having to call `session_start` first.

Comment: One of the best q&a on sessions! I finally understand what's really going on. +1 to all of you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's go to the source. Literally.

[session_destroy()](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c#L122-L141) and [session_regenerate_id()](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c#L1907-L1943) are both implemented in *ext/session/session.c* in the PHP source. It's obvious from a quick reading that if you pass true to `session_regenerate_id`, it calls [s_destroy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sessionhandlerinterface.destroy.php) on the underlying session save handler, which is the exact same call as the one made by `session_destroy`. This behaviour has remained the same since at least 2005, according to an svn blame.

`session_destroy` does make two additional calls to `php_rshutdown_session_globals` and `php_rinit_session_globals`. Among other things, this causes `session_destroy()` to call the close function in the save handler, but this is done automatically when the request has completed, anyway (see [PHP_RSHUTDOWN_FUNCTION](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c#L2385)). It also resets the session to the inactive state (like before calling `session_start`), which can be seen by calling [session_status()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) (introduced in php 5.4).

**The take away from all of this is that you never have to call `session_destroy` *before* calling `session_regenerate_id(true)`. However, if you want to reset the session, you still have to call it *after*, because otherwise the session will still be active, and the current contents of `$_SESSION` will be written to storage by the save handler when the request has finished.**

Comment: Thank you! That also means that for a script that does not use any global session variables - as in my question - and that explicitly sets $_SESSION to an empty array, session_destroy does not bring any additional benefits!

Answer (score 5):

The `session_regenerate_id()` function is meant to copy or move the session data based on its corresponding identifier; it's typically used when a user logs in to prevent session fixation. Afterwards, the session is still active and it can be accessed with `$_SESSION`.

The `session_destroy()` removes the current session data. Afterwards, the session is gone and you can only start a new session using `session_start()`.

If a user signs out of your site, the most appropriate action is to destroy the session altogether; i.e. use `session_destroy()`.

Btw, `session_register()` and `session_unset()` are deprecated and shouldn't be used.