# session_regenerate_id() vs session_id(randomString)

Tags: php, session

What is the distinct difference between `session_id($randomString)` and `session_regenerate_id()`? Both seem to change session id:

> **session_regenerate_id()** will replace the current session id with a new one, and keep the current session information.
>
> **session_id()** is used to get or set the session id for the current session.

If I get it right, `session_regenerate_id()` creates a new session file and copies data over with an option to delete an old file; whilst `session_id($randomString)` just changes the session id in the existing file.

If so, what are the benefits of copying files? How is it better from preventing session fixation point of view?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3319280/3324556), nor any other I found, does not answer my question.

Comment: If you read the two corresponding manual pages there are distinct differences (albeit a little subtle) but I am not able at the moment to write a full answer for this at the moment, there is *some* overlap between the two functions, but also clear differences in behaviour.

Comment: the details of what each of these php methods is doing behind the scenes is not something I have found documented anywhere, which is odd to me, because I feel like it matters a lot for a secure and reliable session implementation... thanks for this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, so I did some testing to find the differences in the three different options (`session_id($id)` after `session_start()`, `session_regenerate_id()` and `session_regenerate_id(true)`). This is the result of what actually happens:

---

### session_id($id) after session_start

Calling the session id function after session_start will change the session id. At the end of the page load, the current session contents will write a new session file. This will leave the old session file as well and it won't be updated with any changes. However, **`session_id` doesn't send out a new session cookie**. This is done by `session_start`, even when `session_id` is called before `session_start`. On the next page load, the old session id is passed and loaded with the same data as the start of the last page load (new session changes would have been saved to the new id).

---

### session_regenerate_id() and session_regenerate_id(true)

`session_regenerate_id()` will create and change the session id, transferring the session to the new file and send out the cookie. Passing `true` as an argument will also delete the old session file, omitting the argument will leave it.

---

As far as session fixation, both `session_id($id)` and `session_regenerate_id()` would actually be worse as you are creating new sessions while leaving the old session files around to be hijacked. The only option that might help with fixation would be to call `session_regenerate_id(true)` passing the argument.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks! Worth mentioning, that in any case, either after `session_id()` or `session_regenerate_id([true])` one should call `session_start()` to take over the new identifier.

Comment: @Nordenheim, actually, session_regenerate_id is meant to be called after a session has started. It changes the session id of the current session and sends out a new cookie. So no need to call session_start after it. Changing the session via session_id, you should call session_start or else you just create a new session file and the client is never told about the new generated session id.

Answer (score 1):

The `session_id` function will just change the session id and update the session cookie on the client.
The `session_regenerate_id` function will act like the `session_id` one with the additional session migration on the server.
In fact as you can read from the docs of the `session_id` function, it needs to be called before the `session_start` function, otherwise it may be lay you to a session loss.

**Example**:

Conditions:

- You're using file based session (php default)

Description:

- You start a new session for the current user, the generated session id is '1234abc' and the session save handler saves the session information in `/tmp/sess_1234abc`.
- The user will now leave your app
- The user comes back to your app and the session save handler retrieves the session id '1234abc' from the session cookie; then the session save handler will load the session data file (`/tmp/sess_SESSID` in this case `/tmp/sess_1234abc`)
- Now you change the session id to 'myTestSession' using the `session_id` function
- At this point the user session cookie gets updated
- The user leaves your app
- The user comes back to your app but the session save handler couldn't retrieve the session data, in fact it will look for the `/tmp/sess_MyTestSession` file but the session has not been changed by the `session_id` function so is still `/tmp/sess_1234abc`!

So if you want to prevent session fixation the way to go is definitely `session_regenerate_id`

Answer (score 1):

in a way `session_regenarate_id()` includes `session_id()` internally.

> `session_id()` is a way to get or set the session identifier. It
>   doesn't handle session `sess_*` files. You place it before
>   `session_start` in order to indicate the session identifier. Cookie
>   creation and session file creation are `session_start` work later on.

On the other hand

> `session_regenarate_id()` is something that does not simply set the session
>   identifier but also get your session data from the old `sess_*` file
>   and append it to the new one (with the random id) and create a new `cookie`. Depending on
>   the `delete_old_session` parameter in `session_regenarate_id()` if set
>   to `true` it will delete the old associated session file, otherwise it
>   will remain as a file but it will be empty of all session data.

Comment: I can't find this second point about the internal work of `session_regenerate_id` documented anywhere... thanks for describing it.