# PHP - Session doesnt work on mobile

Tags: php, session, session-variables

For login im using a `session_start()`, for desktop its works fine, but on mobile, it doesnt work. When I make a `session_id()` with variable, for example, `session_id('login')` its works on mobile, but break other sessions on other computers. But when `session_id()` is generated automatically, it doesn't work on mobile. What should I do?

My session_start code on index.php

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    session_id();
}
```

Whole code for login.php file

```
<?php
require('config.php');
$usernameOK = false; $passwordOK = false;
if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $UserQuery = "SELECT username FROM `members` WHERE username='$username'";
        $userTestResult = mysqli_query($connection, $UserQuery);
        $usernameTEST = mysqli_num_rows($userTestResult);
        if($usernameTEST == 1){$usernameOK = true;}

        $PasswordQuery = "SELECT password FROM `members` WHERE username='$username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$PasswordQuery);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

        if (password_verify($password, $row[0])){$passwordOK = true;}

        if($usernameOK == true && $passwordOK == true){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        }else{
            $error_message = "Incorrect login data";
        }
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        header("Location: ../");
        exit;
    }else{?>
    <form class="login-form" method="POST">
        <?php if(isset($error_message)){ ?><div class="mini-mes error"> <?php echo $error_message; ?> </div><?php } ?>

        <span class="placeholder">username</span>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" required>

        <span class="placeholder">password</span>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="password" required>

        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <a class="form-link" href="register.php">Register</a>
    </form>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Have you check if cookies are enabled in your mobile device?

Comment: @RicardoOrtegaMagaña yes, the cookies are enabled on my mobile device

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @RicardoOrtegaMagaña im using a iPhone and Safari browser, but it also happens with iPhone Chrome

Comment: Could you check if the "redirection" after setting the data in the session variable, it's the same as the page where it generated, in example: http://www.example.com and maybe the redirection looks like http://example.com, should be the same, watching the WWW

Comment: The page eliminated the http: / /www . example . com and the http: / / example.com  my bad.

Comment: @RicardoOrtegaMagaña My login links is example.com/login.php, after submit its redirect to example.com

Comment: So you are saying it doesn't work, but that could mean a million different things. What are you expecting, and what is happening? Are you getting an error? What do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: @jmarkmurphy when Im logging in, its redirect to homepage and session not started, Im not logged in, but when Im input a incorrect login data, its shows a error

Comment: did you put session_start() on the top of login.php

Comment: @css.cutter yes

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My problem was on server-side the `session.save_path` not definied to my server. Thanks a lot to all, who helped me :)

Comment: How does this explain it working on desktop but not mobile?

Answer (score 6):

Not really sure what your code does, because I dont see anything regarding setting the username or anything of that sort. What your code does is, it starts the session and checks if username variable in session is set, and if YES, it calls `session_id`.

Can you use this to check if the session is created properly?

```
session_start();
if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_NONE)
{
echo session_id();
}
```

Starts a session and shows you the session ID if the session_status is not `PHP_SESSION_NONE`

Comment: I tested your solution, but still doesn't work, even on IE 11

Comment: My login link for is example.com/login.php, after submit its redirect to example.com and not logged in. Like session not started

Comment: Do you get an error when you call the session variables?

Comment: Thats the session id that you see which means you have a session running :)

Comment: Ok, on desktop its logged in, but on mobile or IE 11 it shows that not logged in

Comment: Drop the whole code so we can iron out the problem. Cant help much without the code.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do a session_id() to start a session, session_start() is enough.

I've tested the following on Safari on iPhone 6 (just add the db query part back if you want):

**testa.php**

```
<?php
//require('config.php');

session_start();
echo "Session ID: ".session_id()." <br>\n";

$usernameOK = false;
$passwordOK = false;

if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $usernameOK = true;
    $passwordOK = true;

    if ($usernameOK == true && $passwordOK == true) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    } else {
        $error_message = "Incorrect login data";
    }
}

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("Location: ../");
    exit;
} else {
?>
    <form class="login-form" method="POST">
        <?php if (isset($error_message)) { ?>
            <div class="mini-mes error"> <?php echo $error_message; ?> </div><?php } ?>

        <span class="placeholder">username</span>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" required>

        <span class="placeholder">password</span>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="password" required>

        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <a class="form-link" href="register.php">Register</a>
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

**testb.php**

```
<?php

session_start();
echo "Session ID: ".session_id()." <br>\n";
echo "Data stored in session: {$_SESSION['username']}<br>\n";
```

1. Clear data/cookies on your mobile browser (or just go into incognito mode). This will make sure you "start from scratch".
2. Open **testa.php** on your mobile browser. Take note of the session id shown. Enter your login details and tap Submit. The next page may show blank.
3. Open **testb.php**. Again, take note of the session id shown. It should be equal to the session id shown in test1.php. If they are different then it is possible your mobile browser is configured not to accept cookies.

I've personally tested this on Safari on iPhone 6 and I was able to get the username data from session.

PS. A friendly reminder: don't forget to escape the data you use in queries (i.e. $username and $password). Use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), or use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). For security.

Comment: Still the same problem, iPhone doesn't start the session. And now its show a error - `Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()` (Im updated my post)

Comment: Its probably because you already have session_start() in your config.php. Also when you call session_id() do not put in parameters. I've updated my post to include instructions to see if your browser accepts/rejects the session cookies.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are experiencing some conflict issues:

My session_start code

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    session_id();
} else if (!isset($_SESSION)){
   session_start();
}
```

Whole code for login.php file

```
<?php
require('config.php');
$usernameOK = false; $passwordOK = false;
if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $UserQuery = "SELECT username FROM `members` WHERE username='$username'";
        $userTestResult = mysqli_query($connection, $UserQuery);
        $usernameTEST = mysqli_num_rows($userTestResult);
        if($usernameTEST == 1){$usernameOK = true;}

        $PasswordQuery = "SELECT password FROM `members` WHERE username='$username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$PasswordQuery);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

        if($usernameOK == true && password_verify($password, $row[0])){
            if (isset($_SESSION)){
               $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            } else{
               session_start();
               $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            }
        }else{
            $error_message = "Incorrect login data";
        }
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        header("Location: ../");
        exit;
    }else{?>
    <form class="login-form" method="POST">
        <?php if(isset($error_message)){ ?><div class="mini-mes error"> <?php echo $error_message; ?> </div><?php } ?>

        <span class="placeholder">username</span>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" required>

        <span class="placeholder">password</span>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="password" required>

        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <a class="form-link" href="register.php">Register</a>
    </form>

<?php } ?>
```

In the index.php on the first line I have -> REMOVE THAT, PUT FIRST ROUTINE OF SESSION CHECKING

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)){
   session_start();
}
```

EDIT: I noted that you're using  [header](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php) function to redirect to the index page. It's important avoid such redirects unless you're sending user out of your system, because some environments doesn't work well with them. I suggest to change your routine to user POST/GET http routines instead:

Inside validateSession.php

outside validateSession, NOTHING about sessions rules, concentrate everything there

index.php/head.php/some code that always starting in every page start only that:

```
<?php 
include_once('validateSessions.php'); 
?>
```

Your form:

```
<form class="login-form" action="index.php" method="POST"> 
<?php if(isset($error_message)){ ?><div class="mini-mes error"> <?php echo $error_message; ?> </div><?php } ?> 

<span class="placeholder">username</span> 
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" required> 

<span class="placeholder">password</span> 
<input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="password" required> 

<button type="submit">Login</button> 
<a class="form-link" href="register.php">Register</a> 
</form>
```

EDIT: I reviewed your routine, pay attention on validateSessions.php, I was forgetting to load session_start() in every routine that called the file. Put validateSessions inside your include directory.

UPDATE: Even my code helping the OP, the main problem was the SESSION configuration into php.ini file with session.save_path, causing issues about session routines. The php.ini fix solved the problem, the code I expect that helped OP to think about some routines towards Session stuff.

Comment: And for this my issue is not fixed :( I dont know whats happens

Comment: Put an echo in every routine and trace where you lose the session or even if it does not start

Comment: but why its starts on desktop and on mobile not?

Comment: Mobile it's more restricts about sessions, as far I know. Btw, I strongly advise you to set watchpoints (with echoes/var_dumps and die/exits)  to check if your session is starting, AT LEAST. If aren't, it's a problem from your environment.

Comment: on index.php its doesnt return `$_SESSION['username']` on mobile, but on desktop return

Comment: hmm, now even on desktop its doesnt return a value and mobile too :/

Comment: Are you sure that $username is filled by DB in your mobile phone? Try to use a test string 'username' and see if the session stores the value

Comment: where I will need to put that? :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145739/discussion-between-carlos-alexandre-and-daniels-jirgensons).

Comment: Are you absolutely sure "Private Browsing" isn't enabled on your mobile browser? This can and will effect how session cookies are dealt with .

Answer (score 1):

Probably your session is not set. Depending on the PHP version you use, check your session.

For versions of PHP **>= 5.4.0**

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

For versions of PHP **< 5.4.0**

```
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
```

Comment: Where did you put the session_start()?

Comment: @aljof my session_start is on index.php first line

Answer (score 1):

[Cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) definitely work on mobile browsers.

Comment: Yes, but mobile doesnt check the session

Answer (score 1):

I have simplified the code and the session is started when all checks are passed.

```
<?php
require('config.php');
if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $UserQuery = "SELECT password FROM `members` WHERE username='$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $UserQuery);
    $usernameTEST = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($usernameTEST == 1){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        if(password_verify($password, $row[0])) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("Location: ../");
            exit();
        }
    }

    $error_message = "Incorrect login data";
}

<form class="login-form" method="POST">
    <?php if(isset($error_message)){ ?><div class="mini-mes error"> <?php echo $error_message; ?> </div><?php } ?>

    <span class="placeholder">username</span>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" required>

    <span class="placeholder">password</span>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="password" required>

    <button type="submit">Login</button>
    <a class="form-link" href="register.php">Register</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Still the same issue, when im login, its redirect to index.php and nothing happens

Comment: only three lines. which part is not working? session_id returns a value, you have to use `echo session_id();`

Comment: I dont know, on desktop all was working fine, but problem is on mobile device. `session_id` returns a value

Comment: you have to use echo

Answer (score 1):

Simplified the code to make it easier to understand.Ignoring checks for username and password etc. You're basically trying to set a session variable. That happens in login.php. Code for that is.

```
 <?php
 $username = "Umesh";
 if (isset($_SESSION))
 {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
 }
 else
 {
           session_start();
           $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
 }
 print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

In index.php you're trying to check the session status.  The code is below.

```
 if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
session_id();
} else if (!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
print_r($_SESSION);
```

The above works for me on every browser and device.  I even tested chrome on iphone. It seems to work fine. Please check this and see if it works. If not, we will have to check your webserver to see, what the issue is, with session objects on that system.

I verified that  print_r ($_SESSION) was same in both cases.

Comment: Still the same, and I dont know why :/

Comment: On desktop its return `Array ( [username] => username )` but on mobile `Array ( )`

Comment: Can you put this code in two separate files in your server and share the link? I have this code in the following links.
http://ec2-54-255-212-88.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/testing/login.php

http://ec2-54-255-212-88.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/testing/

Answer (score 1):

Why you use session_id(). session I am always use this login system. I have no problem Desktop or Mobile session.

PHP code

```
&lt;?php
session_start();
include 'connect.php'; 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST["uname"], ENT_QUOTES, "ISO-8859-1");
  $username = stripslashes($username);
  $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST["pass"], ENT_QUOTES, "ISO-8859-1");
  $password = stripslashes($password);

  $sql="SELECT * FROM member WHERE username= '$username' AND password='$password' AND status='1' ";
  $result=mysql_db_query($dbname,$sql);
  $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
  $num=mysql_num_rows($result);
  $msg= "<h3 style='padding:0px;margin:0px;font-size:16px;background:#fff;padding:8px;'><font color='red'><center>Incorrect login data</center></font></h3>";

  if($num>0)
  {
    $_SESSION['id']       =$row[0];
    $_SESSION['fullName'] =$row[1];
    $_SESSION['username'] =$row[2];
    $_SESSION['password'] =$row[3];
    $_SESSION['email']    =$row[4];
    $_SESSION['userType'] =$row[5];
    $_SESSION['status']   =$row[6];
    header('location:index.php');
  }
}
?>
```

My HTML Form

```
    <form method="post">
      <p><?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { echo $msg; } ?> </p>
      <div>
      <input type="text" name="uname" class="form-control" placeholder="Username..." required="" />
      </div>
      <div>
      <input type="password" name="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password..." required="" />
      <p align="right">Forgot it?</a></p>
      </div>
      <div>
      <button class="btn btn-success submit" type="submit" name="submit"> Login   <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i></button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove  session_start(); in index.php 
and Add this in your config.php

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) 
{
    session_start();
}
```

Comment: Still the same problem as before

Answer (score 0):

Going by your last comment I guess it is due to the query string you are using. Basically using `password` as a column name sometimes breaks the query as `password` is also a mysql keyword.
Also, regarding your session you can refer to [session_id() vs session_regenerate_id()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367982/session-regenerate-id-vs-session-idrandomstring) for further details regarding the functions. `Session_id('login')` basically sets the session id to login which works on your mobile device as this creates the session with the specific static id. However, you can try using `session_regenerate_id(true)` to see if it helps.

Also i tried executing the code by putting static value as username as follows

**login.php**

```
 <?php
    $username = "deadlock";
    if (isset($_SESSION))
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    }
    else
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    }
     print_r($_SESSION);
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    session_regenerate_id(true);
} else if (!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
print_r(session_id());
```

I started using index.php directly using the phone which printed the output as `array()` with no values.turned out that the **Login.php** file is not executed.after I explicitly executed **Login.php** the index.php printed the session array. Can you make sure that the login php file is properly executed.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Check that session_start() is placed before any browser output.  I have found that Chrome on Desktop can be a lot more forgiving then other browsers as well as Mobile Chrome

Answer (score -1):

This problem is generated with Chrome "Lite Mode" to reduce data load throw the Phone. If you use secret navigation so the lite mode is automatically disable an page work correctly. You have to disable "Lite Mode" on Chrome.
This is the final solution.